# How can I write to browser console from Blazor Server

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

When you use ILogger or Console.WriteLine in WebAssembly the logs are written in the browser console. But in the Blazor Server apps the logs don't appear in the browser console. I want to see the logs in the browser console (because it's very useful) while I debugging the app.

Answer (score 2):

You can invoke the console via JsInteropt :

```
<button @onclick=@(()=>ConsoleLog("Hello")) >Hello</button>
@code {
    [Inject]
    public IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }

    public async void ConsoleLog(string message)
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("console.log", message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry my question has lack a bit. I mean over like Console.WriteLine or ILogger

Comment: @iBener you would have to inject the `IJSRunitme` in the constructor of your logger service/broker and call the same method.